# Concentration of norm of linearly transformed normal random vector as dimension go to infinity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, random-matrices

Following no response, recently asked on [MO.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358885/concentration-of-norm-of-linearly-transformed-normal-random-vector-as-dimension)

Let $X=(X_1 \dots X_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n, X_i\sim N(0,1),  iid.$ Let $B: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ be the diagonal linear map: $Bx_k:= x_k/ {k}, 1 \le k \le n.$ Then $||B||_F^2= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}$. **Then is:  $lim_{n \to \infty}|E||BX||  -  ||B||_F |=0?$. What is $E||BX||$ anyway?** Note that, if $B$ were $I_n,$ the answer would be yes even for cases $X_i$ non Gaussian, c.f. [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325862/expectation-of-the-norm-of-a-random-vector?rq=1).

---

**Motivation for this question (not needed to answer the question): concentration**

Note that: $E[||BX||^2]=||B||_F^2, ||.||_F$ denoting the Frobenius norm. For those familiar with [concentration of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure) OR [Hanson-Wright inequality for concentration of quadratic forms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2872), we could expect that $||BX||^2$ should be concentrated around $E[||BX||^2]=||B||_F^2.$ **My question is: is the concentration asymptotically tight when dimension goes to infinity?**

**Following motivation from the fact: $lim_{n \to \infty}|E||X||  - \sqrt{n}  |=0,$ I wonder: does $lim_{n \to \infty}|E||BX||  -  ||B||_F |=0?$** Or if not, could we at least have: $\frac{||BX||}{||B||_F } \to _{p} 1$ in probability, as dimension $n \to \infty?$

I *purposefully* chose $B$ above so that the ratio of Frobenius norm to operator norm of $B$, i.e. $\frac{||B||_F}{||B||}$ does not go to $\infty.$ If it *does* go to infinity as $n \to \infty$, then we do have:  $\frac{||BX||}{||B||_F } \to _{p} 1$, which follows from Hanson-Wright inequality. See the top/first equation from P.144 from [this book](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html#).

Comment: Why can't you adapt the idea from the MO post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After typing my answer below, I saw that it is essentially what was written on MO. Since I give a few more details, my answer might still be interesting to you.

Unfortunately, what you want to show is not true, which can be seen as follows:
Since $\gamma := \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2} < \infty$, the monotone convergence theorem shows that
$$
  Y := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-2} X_k^2 \in L^1(\Bbb{P}),
$$
where $\Bbb{P}$ is your underlying probability measure.
Define $Y_n := \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-2} X_k^2$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Note that $Y \geq 0$.
Define $Z := \sqrt{Y} \in L^2(\Bbb{P})$, and note that $Y$ (and hence $Z$)
is *not almost surely constant*.
Indeed, if $Y$ was almost surely constant, we would have $Y \equiv \Bbb{E}[Y] = \gamma$
almost surely, and hence
$$
  \gamma
  = \gamma \cdot \Bbb{E}[X_1^2]
  = \Bbb{E} [X_1^2 Y]
  = \Bbb{E} [X_1^4] + \sum_{k=2}^\infty k^{-2} \Bbb{E} [X_1^2] \Bbb{E}[X_k^2]
  = 3 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2} - 1
  = 2 + \gamma,
$$
which is a contradiction.
Here, I used that $\Bbb{E}[X_1^4] = 3$.

Since $Z$ is not almost surely constant, we have a *strict* inequality
in the following application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
  \Bbb{E} [\| B X \|]
  = \Bbb{E} \sqrt{Y_n}
  \leq \Bbb{E} \sqrt{Y}
  =    \Bbb{E} [1 \cdot Z]
  <    \sqrt{\Bbb{E}[1^2]} \cdot \sqrt{\Bbb{E}[Z^2]}
  =    \sqrt{\gamma} .
$$
From this, it is easy to see
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty}
    \big|
      \Bbb{E} \| B X \|
      - \| B \|_F
    \big|
  \geq \lim_{n \to \infty}
         \| B \|_F
       - \lim_{n \to \infty}
           \Bbb{E} \| B X \|
  \geq \sqrt{\gamma} - \Bbb{E} [\sqrt{Y}]
  >    0 .
$$

Finally, note that if we had $\frac{\| B X \|}{\| B \|_F} \to 1$ in probability, then we would
have convergence almost everywhere for a subsequence and then
$\| B X \| = \frac{\| B X \|}{\| B \|_F} \cdot \| B \|_F \to \sqrt{\gamma}$ almost everywhere
along this subsequence.
Since $0 \leq \| B X \| = \sqrt{Y_n} \leq \sqrt{Y} = Z \in L^2(\Bbb{P}) \subset L^1(\Bbb{P})$,
the dominated convergence theorem then shows
$$
  \Bbb{E} \| B X \|
  \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \Bbb{E}[\sqrt{\gamma}],
$$
contradicting what was shown above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, upvoted! I'll surely go over your answer tomorrow and might comment here if I've further questions - much appreciate the detail - I'm sure it'd be very helpful!

Comment: Thanks again! A quick follow up qn: does the proof also show that $\frac{||BX||}{E||BX||}$ does not converge to $1$ in prob.? It's because if it does, passing to a subseq, $\frac{||BX||}{E||BX||} \to 1$ a.s. But this means: $\frac{||BX||/||B||_F }{E||BX||/||B||_F} \to 1$ a.s. For the denominator, both $ lim_{n \to \infty}E||BX||, ||B||_F $ exist (being monotone), but $E||BX||/||B||_F \to l \ne 1.$ This shows: for the numerator, $ ||BX||/||B||_F \to l \ne 1. $  a.s. So, $ ||BX||^2/{||B||_F}^2 \to l^2 \ne 1. $ By DCT: $ E[||BX||^2/{||B||_F}^2] \to l^2 \ne 1.$ But LHS $\equiv 1.$ Contradiction.

Comment: Also, two more quick questions: to ensure the existence of $Y$ itself a.s., can we use Kolmogorov's three-series theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem)?


And finally, the proof seems to go through any infinite sequence of iid random variables with the first four moments bounded and positive, right? Normality was never used I think , except $EX_1^4=3,$ but it seems $ EX_1^4  \ne 1 < \infty$ was enough in the part where you showed $Y$ isn't a.s. constant.